# First numbers stuck together and horizontal in the label (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

im makin a machine for *prime number*,But I want the output of the numbers to be stuck together and horizontal, for example:

```
>>2,3,5,7,11,13,......
```

but machine do this:

[image]

It is neither horizontal nor joined together
my code:

```
from tkinter import *
def prime():
    a = int(spin.get())
    for number in range(a + 1):
        if number > 1:
            for i in range(2,number):
                if (number % i) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                Label(app,text=number,).pack()
app = Tk()
app.maxsize(300,300)
app.minsize(300,300)
spin = Entry(app,font=20)
spin.pack()
Button(app,text="prime numbers",command=prime).pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by storing the numbers in a list (`result`) and then joining them at the end.

```
def prime():
    a = int(spin.get())
    result = []
    for number in range(a + 1):
        if number > 1:
            for i in range(2,number):
                if (number % i) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                result.append(str(number))
    Label(app, text = ",".join(result)).pack()
```

The numbers have to be stored as strings so `join` will work.

**Edit**

To wrap every 10 numbers, add the following in place of `Label(app, ...)` after the for loop:

```
for i in range(0, len(result), 10):
        Label(app, text = ",".join(result[i:i+10])).pack()
```

Comment: hey i have new problem window have a limit in size ,so if number is high numbers is so biger than window limit! I want to go to the next line after 10 numbers, can you do anything?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how to do that